# BootStrap fluid grid system shifts over nav bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, containers, navbar, fluid-layout

So, I've spent about 9 hours straight on this, and I was wondering if anyone could help me.
For some reason, this block of code shifts over my navbar to the left by about a pixel. I don't really understand why, I thought I screwed up with some tags, but after experimenting, I've narrowed the problem down right to [here][1].

`[1]: http://pastebin.com/2iZwnFZs` (not available anymore)

Comment: What navbar? I moved your code to Bootply and it looks fine there http://www.bootply.com/63466, but there is no navbar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to share my actual code with you! http://pastebin.com/e5WDqwdk is what shifts over, http://pastebin.com/B9CVXuns is what it should be like (that's another page that works correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! 
A friend told me to use CSS to fix this, here's the CSS I used:

body {overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;}

The cause of the navbar shift was the scroll bar, the code above will hide the scroll bar when it overflows data horizontally.